# How to randomly fetch from a JSON file and render it into a FlatList?

Tags: json, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have an app which fetch data from a JSON file. The problem is, it fetches the data from top to bottom. I want it to fetches randomly within the JSON file. How would I achieve this?

This is how I fetch the JSON:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = ''
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });  
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson.product,
        dataBackup: responseJson.product,
        isLoading: false
      });
      })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

Comment: What is the type of content of the data ? Arrays ?

Comment: yes, that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reading a file there is no way to change the order of content.
However, once the json is parsed, since your `product` key is an array, you can shuffle this array when you setting the state.

You can use the shuffle function from this answer
[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Alternatively if you're using lodash, there is `shuffle` function for collections :
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#shuffle

Your final code would be:

```
// import shuffle function from linked anwser,
// or with lodash :
import { shuffle } from "lodash";

// ...

componentDidMount() {
  const url = "";
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: shuffle(responseJson.product),
        dataBackup: responseJson.product,
        isLoading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```